# Can I run bitcoind without downloading new blocks?

Tags: blockchain, daemon

I want to run `bitcoind` to interact with the daemon, but having bitcoin download new blocks and verify them is taking a toll on my CPU. I do not want the latest data - I just want the daemon to be running. Is there a way to prevent bitcoin from downloading new data?

Comment: Use the `-proxy` option with some not existing proxy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essentially, you want to run `bitcoind` while connected to the network to download all the blocks, then disconnect it from the network so it no longer downloads new data. There are several possible ways to do this, from least to most drastic:

- Use the `-proxy` option to specify a proxy that does not exist.
- Use a software firewall to prevent `bitcoind` from communicating with the network.
- Run `bitcoind` in a virtual machine and turn off its network access.
- Physically disconnect the machine from the network.